# Finding the PMF and CDF of $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}\left(4, \dfrac{1}{3}\right)$ and $Y = 2X$. Find the PMF and CDF of $Y$.

I am not exactly sure if I am on the right track with either of these, but I found the PMF of $X$ to be
$$P(X=0)=\frac{16}{18},\ P(X=1)=\frac{32}{18},\ P(X=2)=\frac{8}{27},\ P(X=3)=\frac{8}{81}.$$
Then, I found the support of $Y$ to be $\{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5\}$. So, I got the PMF of $Y$ as 
$$P(Y=0)=\frac{16}{18},\ P(Y=0.5)=\frac{32}{18},\ P(X=1)=0,\ P(X=1.5)=\frac{8}{81}.$$
However, I am not sure if that is right and I am not sure how to find the CDF.

Comment: how can $P(X = 1) > 1$ ???

Answer (score 2):

**Starting of, you have one HUGE mistake. You have yielded a probability greater than one. Your PMF also should be a function of the trials $k$ needed.**

$X \sim \rm{Bin}(4,1/3)$ means that $n=4$ and $p=1/3$. Thus, the PMF of $X$, is :

$$f(k,n,p) = \mathbb{P}(k;n,p)=\mathbb{P}(X=k) = \binom{4}{k}\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^k\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{4-k}$$

Thus, if $Y=2X$, then the PMF is :

$$\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\mathbb{P}(2X=k)=\mathbb{P}(X=k/2) = \binom{4}{k/2}\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^{k/2}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{4-k/2} $$

The CDF of $X$, is :

$$F(k;n,p)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq k)= \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k \rfloor} \binom{4}{i}\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^i\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{4-i}$$

where $n=4$ and $p=1/3$ in all of the above.

Thus, finally, the CDF of $Y=2X$ is :

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq k) = \mathbb{P}(2X \leq k) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq k/2) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \binom{4}{i}\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^i\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{4-i}$$

Comment: ok that makes sense. I'm wondering, is there a way to determine the support of Y? Or even X for that matter? Is it not {0,1,2,3,4} for X?

Comment: Hi. The support for the binomial distribution is $k \in \{0,1, \dots, n\}$. In this particular example, it is $n=4$, thus the support of $X$ is $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. In the case of $Y$, the support is the $k/2$ trials and thus its integer, which means that the support of $Y$ is $k \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Ok, and the PMF of Y=2X isn't supposed to sum to 1? Because when I plug in those supports I am getting 0.8719 < 1.

Comment: Take note that the values of the support overlap since it's the integer part of $k$. The support is just a set, the values you plug in may come twice.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what values are overlapping and why?

Comment: What would this like written as a piece-wise function? The only values in supp(Y) in which I get a non-zero number are for P(Y=0)=P(X=0)=0.1975 and for P(Y=2)=P(2X=2)=P(X=1)=0.39506, and they clearly do not sum to 1.

Comment: Divide the support points by 2. Find the integer parts of them. You will observe that you will have two cases of 0 and two cases of 1. Apply the CDF now (which describes exactly that, take a look at the sum index) and you will have your probability sum up to 1.

Comment: @Rebellos $Y=2X$ so the support for $Y$ is $\{0,2,4,6, 8\}$.

Comment: So, the PMF of X is the same as the for Y (with the only difference being the support points)?

Comment: No. Please pay attention to the sum factors.